# how to disable a click while editing

Tags: html, asp.net, mvvm, knockout.js

Following is the code to which the disbale thing needs to be applied.While i have added observable in my knockout code for save function

html

````
    <tr>
        <td>
            <a  href="#" data-bind="{click:$parent.save}">Confirm</a>
        </td>


Knockout

        vm.save = function () {

        var item = vm.selectedItem();
        vm.confirmedRecord(false);```
````

Answer (score 0):

there's not much info to go on but if I interpreted correctly, this is a possible solution..

```js
ko.applyBindings(() => {
  var self = this;
  self.items = ko.observableArray([{
    id: 1,
    name: 'foo'
  }, {
    id: 2,
    name: 'bar'
  }]);
  self.confirmed = ko.observable(false);
  self.save = (item) => console.log('clicked');
  self.toggle = () => {
    self.confirmed(!self.confirmed());
    console.log('buttons: ' + self.confirmed());
  }
});
```

```css
button {
  border: 0;
  background: transparent;
  color: blue;
  text-decoration: none;
}

button:hover:not(:disabled) {
  text-decoration: underline;
  color: red;
  cursor: pointer;
}

button:disabled {
  color: gray;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.4.2/knockout-min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tbody data-bind="foreach: items">
    <tr>
      <td data-bind="text: id"></td>
      <td data-bind="text: name"></td>
      <td>
        <button data-bind="click: save, enable: confirmed">save</button>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>

<a href="#" data-bind="click: toggle">confirm</a>
```

===== ** Update

if it's an ajax request I'd suggest changing your code this way, mind the self.confirming() observable that hides your confirm links for a loading msg.

```js
var $fakeAsync = (api, result) => $.Deferred((dfd) => setTimeout(() => dfd.resolve(result), 500)).promise();

ko.applyBindings(() => {
  var self = this;
  self.confirming = ko.observable();
  self.confirmed = ko.observableArray([]);
  self.confirm = (item) => {
    console.clear();
    self.confirming(item.id);
    var apiUrl = '/api/dostuff&id=' + item.id;
    console.log('confirming api ' + apiUrl);
    $fakeAsync(apiUrl, item.id === 1).done((success) => {
      if (success) self.confirmed.push(item.id);
      console.log(success ? 'confirmed' : 'validation error')
    }).always(() => {
      self.confirming(null);
      console.log('done');
    });
  };
  self.items = ko.observableArray([
    { id: 1, name: 'foo' },
    { id: 2, name: 'bar' }
  ]);

});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/underscore.js/1.9.1/underscore-min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.4.2/knockout-min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tbody data-bind="foreach: items">
    <tr>
      <td data-bind="text: id"></td>
      <td data-bind="text: name"></td>
      <td>
        <a href="#" data-bind="click: confirm, visible: !_.contains(confirmed(), id) && confirming() !== id">confirm</a>
        <span data-bind="visible: confirming() === id">loading..</span>
        <span data-bind="visible: _.contains(confirmed(), id) ">done</span>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Hi Sam, the actual scenario is when i click on Confirm (which is not a button) the data loading takes a long time in which the user tries to click Confirm again and the data gets saved with the number of time the Confirm is click i.e if it is clicked twice the data can be seen twice which is not what I want . I hope you have got some idea by this

Comment: is that an ajax request, clicking on the Confirm? or does it trigger a full page reload?

Comment: its an ajax request

Comment: see my secondary proposal